# Output results of two tables 1:1 comparison true / false

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have 2 tables, one for t1 and another one for their t2. Those are mariaDB

t1 table:

```
      id      |  cash_amount_received
    ----------------------------------
      1              7000
      2              1000
      3              2000
      4              3000
      5              4000
      6              5000
```

t2 table:

```
      id      |      amount
    ----------------------------------
      1              1000
      2              2000
      3              3000
      4              4000
      5              5000
      6              5000
      7              6000
      8              7000
```

I try to achieve this result:

```
 id     |  cash_amount_received|    amount| result
-----------------------------------------------------
  1          7000                    7000    true
  2          1000                    1000    true
  3          2000                    2000    true
  4          3000                    3000    true
  5          4000                    4000    true
  6          5000                    5000    true
  7          null                    5000    false
  8          null                    6000    false
```

But the query I wrote has the following results.

in this query

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.cash_amount_received,  t2.amount, 
IF(t2.id IS NULL, FALSE, TRUE) as result
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id)
```

in thsi result
[image]

How do fix my query?

I desperately need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the tables are backwards for the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t2.id, hospital_payment_data.cash_amount_received, t2.amount, 
       (t1.id IS NOT NULL) as result
FROM t2 LEFT JOIN
     t1
     ON t1.id = t2.id
```

I don't know what `hospital_payment_data` is, but presumably you do.

A `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows rom the *first* table, along with matching columns from the *second* table.   You want all rows from `t2`, so that needs to be the first table reference.

Comment: hospital_payment_data  is t1. I fixed it.
Thank you.
I solved it with your answer.